# Does AWS S3 Java SDK support socks proxy?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, proxy, socks, aws-java-sdk

While exploring the AWS S3 Java SDK,
Found that ClientConfiguration still does not support SOCKS proxy.

```
version=1.11.681
groupId=com.amazonaws
artifactId=aws-java-sdk-s3
```

Do we have some other configuration to set SOCKS proxy for java S3 client?